# how can use lambda to multiply every item in array , but each one have diferent operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

i have this array this:coord= [[1,3,4], [4,4,4]],   each position means 0=grade, 1=minute,2=seconds , i need to do an operation using lambda , to translate the array coord to radians, that means use this formula

```
radians= pi*(grade+(minute+seconds/60)/60)/180
```

im thinking that it should be a diferent operation for grade, minute and seconds but i cant find the answer using just a lambda

```
coord= [[1,3,4],
        [4,4,4]]

f=lambda a,b,c : (a+((b+(c/60))/60))/180

print( f(coord))
```

i tried to take 3 diferents letters,  but it does not work , if you have an idea please tell me

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis(function, 1, coords)`

Comment: why do you need to use `lambda`? You can always define a normal function. `lambda` is never necessary.

Comment: Without numpy you need a loop or list comprehension to apply the calculation to each sublist.

Comment: the exercise requires to use lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine function or change a to x[0], b to x[1]... in lambda

```
def f(x):
    a,b,c = x
    return (a+((b+(c/60))/60))/180
```

and use apply_along_axis function

```
np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, coords)
array([0.00583951, 0.02259877])
```

with labmda it will be

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x : (x[0]+((x[1]+(x[2]/60))/60))/180, 1, coords)
array([0.00583951, 0.02259877])
```

Answer (score -1):

You're close.  You have two problems: (1) you have *two* sets of coefficients, and (2) you gave your function the list, rather than the individual elements.

To get a single computation, choose *one* list and then expand it to the argument list for your function:

```
print( f(*coord[0]))
```

Result:

```
0.005839506172839506
```

With that done, I expect that you can print the two computations in whatever fashion you have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you need to call `f` on each coord. You can use `*` to spread the arguments:

```
In [17]: for pos in coord: 
    ...:     print(f(*pos)) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                                                             
0.005839506172839506
0.022598765432098766
```

With list comprehension:

```
In [18]: [f(*x) for x in coord]                                                                                                                      
Out[18]: [0.005839506172839506, 0.022598765432098766]
```